# converting RDD to dataframe fails on string to date conversion

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, casting

I am working on extracting some data from xml. My overall workflow, which might be inefficient, is:

1. Read xml into a dataframe ('df_individual')
2. Filter unwanted columns
3. Make the target schema (shared below)
4. Convert the dataframe to RDD
5. Create a dataframe using schema and RDD from step 3 and 4

I created the RDD like below:

```
rddd = df_individual.rdd.map(tuple)
```

'df_individual' is the orignal dataframe where read the xml.

Below is the schema:

```
schema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('applicaion_id', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('cd_type', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('cd_title', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('firstname', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('middlename', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('nm_surname', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('dt_dob', types.DateType()),
        types.StructField('cd_gender', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('cd_citizenship', types.StringType())
    ])
```

It fails on

```
df_result = spark.createDataFrame(rddd, schema)
```

The error is

```
TypeError: field dt_dob: DateType can not accept object '1973-02-19' in type <class 'str'>
```

The main purpose of creating the 'df_result' dataframe is having a predefined schema and implicitly casting all the columns where there is difference between RDD and dataframe. This is my first time working with RDD and I couldn't find a straight forward casting mechanism for such a case.

If you can help with solving the casting error or share a better workflow that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is only to get your data into the right schema and transform some string columns into date columns, I would use a `select` combined with [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date).

```python
df.select('applicaion_id', 'cd_type', 'cd_title', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'nm_surname', \
          F.to_date('dt_dob').alias('dt_bob'), \
          'cd_gender', 'cd_citizenship') \
  .printSchema()
```

prints

```
root
 |-- applicaion_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nm_surname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt_bob: date (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_citizenship: string (nullable = true)
```

with the column `dt_bob` having a date datatype.